# Inserting the results of a mysql query into existing table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a an existing table with timestamps and other values and I wanted to create dummy timestamps for each day in the table

For example

```
    timestamp           phase_1 phase_2 phase_3
2014-03-04 12:00:00   0       0        0
2014-03-05 02:00:00   0       0        0
2014=03-06 01:00:00   0       0        0
2014-03-07 00:00:00   0       3        1
```

should result to

```
timestamp           phase_1 phase_2 phase_3
2014-03-04 00:00:00   0       0        0     --<< new
2014-03-04 12:00:00   0       0        0
2014-03-05 00:00:00   0       0        0     --<< new
2014-03-05 02:00:00   0       0        0
2014-03-06 00:00:00   0       0        0     --<< new
2014-03-06 01:00:00   0       0        0
2014-03-07 00:00:00   0       3        1
```

The following query works fine

```
`select * from Table1

right join

(select
        `timestamp`
      , phase_1
      , phase_2
      , phase_3
from Table1

union

select
        date(`timestamp`)
      , 0
      , 1
      , 2
from Table1

order by 
        `timestamp`) `
```

but I am not able to insert the result into the exisiting database

using the following query

```
`INSERT into Table1

select * from Table1

right join

(select
        `timestamp`
      , phase_1
      , phase_2
      , phase_3
from Table1

union

select
        date(`timestamp`)
      , 0
      , 1
      , 2
from Table1

order by 
        `timestamp`) `
```

Which i think is correct but i get a

```
: Every derived table must have its own alias:  error which i am not sure on how to solve
```

Here is the fiddle [enter link description here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/68662/5)

Also, will it be possible to insert dummy timestamp and values  for days which are not there at all in the table?

Suppose there are two days between the first and last rows in the table and there are no timestamps for those days in the table, will it be possible to add those two dates into the table.

I want to avoid trigger and procedures if possible as I am not at all familiar with them and since the table is dynamically generated, i think it wont be possible to use them.

Comment: Your insert should fail because you are trying to put 8 columns into a table with just 4 columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got to use an alias name for your UNION, but you've got to provide an JOIN condition for your right join too. Probably you want to use:

```
INSERT INTO Table1
select a.* from Table1    
right join    
(
    select
        `timestamp`
      , phase_1
      , phase_2
      , phase_3
    from Table1

    union

    select
        date(`timestamp`)
      , 0
      , 1
      , 2
    from Table1

    order by 
        `timestamp`
) as a
ON DATE(a.timestamp) = DATE(Table1.timestamp)
```

**Remarks:**

[What is the difference between Left, Right, Outer and Inner Joins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448023/what-is-the-difference-between-left-right-outer-and-inner-joins) provides a very good explanation of the different joins.

An outer join needs a join condition, an inner join without a condition is the same as an CROSS JOIN, the [cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of both tables (most times one wants to avoid this - but not ever).

If you use a SELECT statement, that works perfectly as SELECT statement alone in a join, then the result of this SELECT statement changes into a derived table and you've got to give this derived table a name so you can use the columns of the derived table.

I hope it will be a little bit more clear now.

Comment: I am still new to joins and unions, can you explain it a bit if you don't mind

Comment: read this :When selecting from and inserting into a table at the same time, MySQL creates a temporary table to hold the rows from the SELECT and then inserts those rows into the target table. However, it remains true that you cannot use INSERT INTO t ... SELECT ... FROM t when t is a TEMPORARY table, because TEMPORARY tables cannot be referred to twice in the same statement or visit here http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/insert-select.html

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense to keep temporary table names, but im still stuck with the syntax errors

Comment: I get a Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 error but the number of columns are the same

Comment: You've got to change the SELECT * in the join expression to `SELECT a.*` because otherwise you have all columns from Table1 plus all columns from the derived table too.

Answer (score 1):

A better (more efficient) way to write this query is to remove the `union` and use `union all` and to remove the join.  The basic query you want seems to be:

```
select `timestamp`, phase_1, phase_2, phase_3
from Table1
union all
select date(`timestamp`), 0, 1, 2
from Table1 t1
group by date(`timestamp`)
having not exists (select 1 from table1 tt1 where tt1.timestamp = date(t1.timestamp))
order by  `timestamp`;
```

The `group by` and `having` clauses in the second query prevent duplicates, if the value already appears in the table.  Honestly, though, it is probably better to have a unique constraint on `timestamp`.

If you want to insert rows into the table, you only need the second portion of the query:

```
INSERT INTO Table1(timestamp, phase_1, phase_2, phase_3)
    select distinct date(`timestamp`), 0, 1, 2
    from Table1
    group by date(`timestamp`)
    having not exists (select 1 from table1 tt1 where tt1.timestamp = date(t1.timestamp));
```

The original data is already there.

To insert a "dummy" timestamp for days not in the table, you need a way to generate rows with those values.  This can be a pain in MySQL.  But, if you have a calendar table that has all the dates, you can do something like:

```
INSERT INTO Table1(timestamp, phase_1, phase_2, phase_3)
    select c.dte, 0, 1, 2
    from calendar c join
         (select min(date(timestamp)) as mind, max(date(timestmp)) as maxd
          from Table1
         ) tmm
         on c.dte between tmm.mind and tmm.maxd and tmm.mind left join
         Table1 t1
         on date(t1.timestamp) = c.dte
    where t1.timestamp is null;
```

Comment: Thanks, but will creating a unique constraint for timestamp not create conflict when inserting the data into the table?

Comment: @Bazinga777 . . . Why would that be an issue?  You seem to want the column to be unique.